# Нахождение индексов нескольких наименьших чисел в списке. python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Как наиболее оптимальным образом найти индексы двух наименьших чисел в списке?

Comment: В списке есть повторы?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Быстрый способ получить значения:

```
from heapq import nsmallest

nsmallest(2, some_list)
```

И их индексы:

```
a, b = map(some_list.index, nsmallest(2, some_list))
```

Comment: интересное решение! Как-то мне раньше `heapq` на глаза не попадалось...

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы *индексы* двух наименьших элементов в списке найти:

```
import heapq

i, j = heapq.nsmallest(2, range(len(lst)), key=lst.__getitem__)
```

Если только сами элементы нужны:

```
a, b = heapq.nsmallest(2, lst)
```

Answer (score 3):

Еще одно решение с использованием - [array.argpartition() из модуля Numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) (гораздо быстрее работает для больших списков):

```
import numpy as np

In [45]: a = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=10)

In [46]: a
Out[46]: array([ 8, 51, 63, 31, 21,  9, 28, 19, 70, 57])

In [47]: a.argpartition(2)[:2]
Out[47]: array([0, 5], dtype=int64)
```

дает такой же результат как и `argsort()`

```
In [48]: a.argsort()[:2]
Out[48]: array([0, 5], dtype=int64)
```

Сравнение производительности для массива из 1.000.000 элемтов:

```
In [32]: a = np.random.randint(0, 1000, size=10**6)

In [33]: lst = a.tolist()

In [34]: a.shape
Out[34]: (1000000,)

In [35]: len(lst)
Out[35]: 1000000

# Кирилл Малышев
In [51]: %timeit sorted(enumerate(lst), key=lambda x:x[1])[:2]
1.68 s ± 10.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# Alban
In [49]: %timeit smallest(lst, 2)
860 ms ± 5.44 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# jfs    
In [37]: %timeit nsmallest(2, range(len(lst)), key=lst.__getitem__)
212 ms ± 4.86 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# avtomato    
In [38]: %timeit a.argsort()[:2]
193 ms ± 10.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Sergey Gornostaev
In [36]: %timeit map(lst.index, nsmallest(2, lst))
75.4 ms ± 2.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# MaxU    
In [39]: %timeit a.argpartition(2)[:2]
10.8 ms ± 37.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Мда, факты - вещь упрямая.

Comment: @0xdb, спасибо :)

Answer (score 2):

Весьма эффективны массивы в NumPy

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([2, 1, 4, 3, 5])
first, second, *other = np.argsort(x)
print(first, second)
```

Comment: Только на больших объёмах данных, так как у нативных вызовов немалые накладные расходы.

Comment: Можно несколько проще: `first, second = x.argsort()[:2]` или `first, second = x.argpartition(2)[:2]`

Comment: @MaxU Отличные варианты, но при использовании argpartition элементы располагаются в произвольном порядке, возможно порядок индексов имеет значение.

Comment: @avtomato, сравните: `a = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=10); a.argsort()[:2]; a.argpartition(2)[:2];` Сравнение производительности - [в моем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/775785/211923)

Comment: @MaxU Если порядок индексов неважен использование argpartition безусловно предпочтительнее, нет накладных расходов на полную сортировку массива.

Comment: @avtomato, по-моему `a.argsort()[:2]` и `a.argpartition(2)[:2]` - будут __всегда__ возвращать одинаковые результаты (включая порядок)...

Comment: @MaxU  Похоже так, вывод отличается только для трех и более значений

Comment: @avtomato, для общего случая: `a.argsort()[:N]` и `a.argpartition(N)[:N]` будут возвращать одинаковые значения ;)

Comment: @MaxU Спорно )                                                                                      In [2]: a = np.array([4, 2, 1, 7, 9])

In [3]: a.argpartition(3)[:3]
Out[3]: array([1, 2, 0])

In [4]: a.argsort()[:3]
Out[4]: array([2, 1, 0])

Answer (score 1):

```
In [71]: smallest = lambda array, n: [array.index(x) for x in sorted(array)[:n]]
```

Более понятный вариант:

```
n [83]: def smallest(array, n):
    ...:     result = []
    ...:     for i in sorted(array)[:n]:
    ...:         result.append(array.index(i))
    ...:     return result
```

Результат в обоих случаях:

```
In [84]: smallest([5, 4, 3, 2, 1], 2)
Out[84]: [4, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted(enumerate([20, 60, 40, 10, 50, 30]), key=lambda x:x[1])
```

Вывод:

```
[(3, 10), (0, 20), (5, 30), (2, 40), (4, 50), (1, 60)]
```

Так получаем конкретно индексы:

```
[i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate([20, 60, 40, 10, 50, 30]), key=lambda x:x[1])]
```

P.S. Совершенно не претендую на эффективность